# Four untrustworthy hadith narrators of hadith said by al Nasa'i?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, islamic-scholar, ilm-ar-rijal

assalaam alaykum

I came across this statement by al Nasa'i where he mentions 4 people known to fabricate ahadeeths. Is he referring to Ibn Sa'd al-Baghdadi and number 4? (Muhammad bin Sa'id Syria??

al-Nasa’i (d. 303 A.H.):
The liars known for fabricating the Hadith of the Messenger of Allah are four. They are: Arba’ah b. Abi Yahya in Madinah, al-Waqidi in Baghdad, Muqatil b. Sulayman in Khurasan and **Muhammad bin Sa’id in Syria**.

Ibn Hajr al-‘Asqalani, Tahdhib al-Tahdhib, vol.9 p.366 No.604, Hyderabad, 1326 A.H.cf. Yusuf ‘Abbas Hashmi, Zaynab bint Jahash, ‘Islamic Culture’ vol.XLI, No.1, Hyderabad (India), 1967 < Source

Comment: Let's see what we can do for you. I'm no expert in hadith and ilm-arijal but one can search!

Comment: Thank you very much...   Im not quoting out of context i found some of these questions in anti muslims sites or shia sites so i come here to get clarification, to know if these narrations are authentic. For the purpose of edification i want to defend my faith from islamophobes and study ahadeeths.

Comment: al-Waqidi was a known historian, who was accused of fabrication if i recall well something i read lately!

Comment: Are you concentrating on Muhammad bin Sa'id from  a-Shaam (Syria)?